# iDangerous Swiper not working with Wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, swipe, swiper.js

first time asking a question here so I'll try to get the etiquette right :)

I'm having trouble getting iDangerous swiper to work with my Wordpress installation. At the moment it's a local install running in BitNami so I can't share a link but I will do my best to explain the situation. My best Google-Fu couldn't turn up an answer.

Firstly, I have Swiper running just fine on a minimal HTML test page, as per the usage instructions at http://www.idangero.us/sliders/swiper/api.php.

Head Example

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="idangerous-swiper.css">
<script defer src="idangerous-swiper-1-9-4-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
    var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container',{
        //Your options here:
        mode:'horizontal',
        loop: true
        //etc..
    });  
}
</script>
```

Body Example

```
<div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">

        <!--First Slide-->
        <div class="swiper-slide">
        <p>Slide One</p>
        </div>

        <!--Second Slide-->
        <div class="swiper-slide">
        <p>Slide Two</p>
        </div>

        <!--Third Slide-->
        <div class="swiper-slide">
        <p>Slide Three</p>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

The above functions as expected in the minimal test but if I do the same in the header.php of my wordpress site, the HTML marked up with the appropriate classes (as per the Body Example above) does not become interactive. The script file appears to have loaded in Firebug but it still isn't taking effect.

I have experimented with "enqueing" the script as the WordPress codex suggests:

```
// Adds swiper js
function MyTheme_swiper() {
wp_enqueue_script(
    'mtswiper',
    get_template_directory_uri() . '/../mychildtheme/js/idangerous-swiper194.js',
    array( 'jquery' )
);
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'MyTheme_swiper' );
```

But this has the same result; the script loads in Firebug but doesn't run on the page.

I also tried shifting the small script that initializes the swiper from the head into a separate JS file and enqued that as well. Again, the new script appears in Firebug's net monitor but doesn't run.

Suspecting that jQuery might be the issue, I changed all of the `$` shortcuts to `jQuery`, another tip from the Worpress Codex.

```
jQuery(function(){
var mySwiper = jQuery('.swiper-container').swiper({
    //Your options here:
    mode:'horizontal',
    loop: true
    //etc..
});
})
```

But still no dice.

Not sure where else to go from here. I can find my way around HTML and CSS pretty well but PHP and JS still make my brain hurt.

Note that early on, I shifted the Swiper CSS from the default `idangerous-swiper.css` into my main stylesheet. This side of it is working as expected.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Pete.

Comment: At first look everything seems to be fine with your code. Can you provide a live link so i can take a look?

Comment: @VladimirKharlampidi Hi Vladimir, I've put a test WordPress site up here [link](http://www.bnctest.com.au/). Hopefully, I've made everything clear on that page. If you have any questions, please feel free to ask. Thanks for your reply! Pt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for so late reply, just saw your answer. The problem is simple, in your startswiper.js file, replace $ with jQuery, like

```
jQuery(function(){
    var mySwiper = jQuery('.swiper-container').swiper({
        //Your options here:
        mode:'horizontal',
        loop: true
        //etc..
    });
})
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks :) Damn, I swear I had it like that originally and changed the shortcuts from "jQuery" to "$" on the advice of the wordpress codex.

Answer (score 0):

Actually one has to use this

```
function MyTheme_swiper() {
wp_enqueue_script(
    'mtswiper', get_template_directory_uri() . '/../mychildtheme/js/idangerous-swiper194.js',
array( 'jquery' ), false, true
);
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'MyTheme_swiper' );
```

One has to check https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/

The objective in here is to put the `script` into `footer`. By default it goes to `header`.